# event conflict for component containing another component

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, element-ui

[image: screenshot]

I have a number input inside a checkbox label, as shown in the screenshot above. When I click the input's plus/minus buttons to change the number, it also changes the checkbox's `checked`-value as an unintended side effect. How do I prevent the side effect?

```html
<template>
  <el-checkbox-group v-model="auditFinding" @change="checkAuditFinding" style="display:flex;flex-direction: column;">
    <el-checkbox v-for="item in auditFindings" :key="item.value" :label="item.label">
      <el-input-number v-if="item.value !== 'N/A'" v-model="item.num" :disabled="item.disabled" :min="0" :max="99" size="small" />
      {{ item.value }}
    </el-checkbox>
  </el-checkbox-group>
</template>
<script>
export default {
  //...
  methods: {
    checkAuditFinding(val) {
      const t = val.toString()     
      this.auditFindings.map(item => {
        if (val.indexOf(item.value) > -1) {
          item.disabled = false
        } else {
          item.disabled = true
        }
      })      
    },
  }
}
</script>
```

Comment: Try moving `@change="checkAuditFinding"` from `el-checkbox-group` to `el-input-number`, or add `.stop` after `@change`  *(`@change.stop`)*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could stop the `click`-event propagation from the `el-input-number` element by using the `@click.native.prevent` event modifiers.

- [`.native`](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-custom-events.html#Binding-Native-Events-to-Components) binds a handler for a native DOM event ([`click`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/click_event) in this case). The caveat to this modifier is it depends on the implementation of `el-nput-number` (the root element must always emit `click` event).
- [`.prevent`](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/events.html#Event-Modifiers) invokes [`Event.preventDefault`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/preventDefault) to effectively cancel the `click`-event, preventing it from reaching the parent checkbox.

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data() {
    return {
      auditFinding: false,
      auditFindings: [
        { value: 11, label: 'label A', disabled: false, num: 1 },
        { value: 22, label: 'label B', disabled: false, num: 2 },
        { value: 33, label: 'label C', disabled: false, num: 3 },
      ]
    }
  },
  methods: {
    checkAuditFinding(e) {
      console.log('checkAuditFinding', e)
    },
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@2.6.11/dist/vue.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/element-ui@2.13.0/lib/theme-chalk/index.css">
<script src="https://unpkg.com/element-ui@2.13.0/lib/index.js"></script>

<div id="app">
  <el-checkbox-group v-model="auditFinding" @change="checkAuditFinding" style="display:flex;flex-direction: column;">
    <el-checkbox v-for="item in auditFindings" :key="item.value" :label="item.label">
      <el-input-number @click.native.prevent
                       v-if="item.value !== 'N/A'"
                       v-model="item.num"
                       :disabled="item.disabled"
                       :min="0"
                       :max="99"
                       size="small"
                       label="item.label" />
      {{ item.value }}
    </el-checkbox>
  </el-checkbox-group>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

No. this is incorrect nest for your goal. 
clicking on any nested element also fires click event on parent.
All you can do is keep checkbox and number as siblings. not inherited.

```
<el-checkbox-group v-model="auditFinding" style="display:flex;flex-direction: column;">
   <div v-for="item in auditFindings">
       <el-checkbox @change="checkAuditFinding" :key="item.value" :label="item.label" />
       <el-input-number v-if="item.value !== 'N/A'" v-model="item.num" :disabled="item.disabled" :min="0" :max="99" size="small" />
       {{ item.value }}
   </div>
</el-checkbox-group>
```